# JQuery - Find and replace text

Tags: jquery, text, replace, find

I'm trying to replace only the text of "Product Number/Description" to "Product Number". Here's the line of code:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="dessearch">&nbsp;Product Number/Description</td>
```

I've attempted the following, but it's also removing the input:

```
$("#ordersearch-page #content table tr td").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("Product Number/Description", "test"); 
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to replace the HTML rather than the text. This will keep the `<input>` element.

```js
$("#ordersearch-page #content table tr td").html(function(i, oldhtml) {
  return oldhtml.replace("Product Number/Description", "test");
});
```

However, this will also lose any dynamic changes to the `<input>` element, such as the value the user entered, or event listeners.

Another option is to put the text into a nested element so you can target it specifically.

```js
$("#ordersearch-page #content table tr td span").text(function(i, oldtext) {
  return oldtext.replace("Product Number/Description", "test");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ordersearch-page">
  <div id="content">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox " name="dessearch "><span>&nbsp;Product Number/Description</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The first option worked like a charm! Unfortunately I can't edit the html directly onto this page so this works out great. Your second option brought up a good alternative point - creating a nested element via jQuery (like wrapping in a span) and then targeting/replacing what's in the span instead.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can use the `contents()` method to retrieve the specific text node, and update its `nodeValue`, like this:

```js
$("table tr td").each((i, el) => {
  let node = $(el).contents().filter((i, n) => n.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && n.nodeValue.trim() !== '')[0];
  node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace("Product Number/Description", "test");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="dessearch">&nbsp;Foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="dessearch">&nbsp;Product Number/Description</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="dessearch">&nbsp;Bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!